# How to display full path of file using ls in linux with -R option in conjunction with grep

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, directory, ls

I'm trying to find a way to recursively look through a directory and display the full path of the files to the right of the files listed. For example, this is what happens when I search and list all files within the directory and subdirectories:

[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj1dA.png)

With Grep, it simply shows the file name but not the full path, which I expected from the first picture. Is there anyway I can show the absolute path?

[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPRlq.png)

I know adding -d option can provide this, but it only shows directories/files at that certain level of the directory and if I wanted to show all levels, I would have to keep track of how many levels there are within the directory and print each level one by one.

[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etu3z.png)

Comment: Please do not post links to external services storing images of text. Please post the text, from your terminal, _as text_ in your quesiton.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), you can use `globstar` to expand the paths from the start:

```
shopt -s globstar
ls -lhd path/**
```

Of course there's also

```
find path -ls
```

Comment: Yea for `find`. Even: `find "$PWD" -ls` for the current directory to emit full paths.

Comment: Would using find path -ls display all files at all layers (files within subdirectories), similar to using the -R recursive argument?

Comment: - Yes, it would.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know anyway to only list files and not directories using find path -ls?

Comment: Sure - `find path -type f -ls`.